# Where should I store the images uploaded by the users?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to store images uploaded by users on a server. I don't consider using Amazon S3 for that, instead I want to save them on a the same server where my Phoenix application is hosted.

Where is the recommended place to store them?

Answer (score 3):

I am unaware of any particular convention that the Elixir/Phoenix community has settled upon as far as a standard directory for uploads. If you're planning to serve the images back to end-users you may want to put them in the `web/static/assets/images` directory but again I don't know if there's a decided convention for that.

You might find [this section](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads) of the Phoenix documentation a good read on the subject.

Comment: so why do you answer if you don't know?

Comment: Even though I do not know of a definite answer to your question, I figured I could still help by posting what I do know. I doubt there is a definite answer to your question since your question is pretty broad.  Recommended place to store images?  Recommended by whom?  Recommended in which circumstances? What caveats are there on the recommendation?  etc. etc.